# Is it possible to fork child processes and wait for them to return in Node/JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to do a certain calculation many many times.  I want to split it over multiple cores, so I want to use child_process.fork(), and then pass each child a chunk of the work.

This works fine, except that my main process (the one that does the fork()) just keeps going after fork()ing and has already terminated by the time the children complete their work.

What I really want to do is wait for the children to finish before continuing execution.

I can't find any good way to do this in Node.  Any advice?

Comment: Look into the async module, which can be used for managing and synchronizing callbacks like this.

Comment: `waitpid` is the system call that you're looking for.  Or you can use the close/end events emitted by child process objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you spawn a new *V8* process via `.fork()`, it returns a new `child` object which implements a communication layer. For instance

```
var cp    = require( 'child_process' ),
    proc  = cp.fork( '/myfile.js' );

proc.on('message', function( msg ) {
    // continue whatever you want here
});
```

and within `/myfile.js` you just dispatch an event when you're done with the work

```
process.send({ custom: 'message' });
```

---

Be aware of the fact that this method indeed spawns a new V8 instance, which eats a good chunk of memory. So you should use that very thoughtfully. Maybe you don't even need to do it that way, maybe there is a more "node like" solution (using `process.nextTick` to calculate heavy data).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've gotten this far.  My problem is, the process which calls fork() continues execution after fork()ing, and by the time the child process responds (with process.send()), the initial process has already terminated so the response is useless.  I'm looking for a way to force my parent process to wait for all children to finish execution before continuing along.  Kind of like wait() in C.

Comment: @user844942: well, that would entirely pervert the node event model. You seriously should seek for another solution which goes hand in hand with event looping and cooperative multitasking.

Comment: As some mentioned above, take a look at the `async` module, that should have the type of `wait` semantics you are looking for.

Comment: @jAndy thanks for your answer.  After giving it some thought I realized I WAS going about it all wrong.

Comment: process.nextTick is *not* the way to process heavy data! It just kicks the can down the road.